# Why does Israel count in many ways as European country?

Tags: europe, israel

My question is, why does Israel count as European country when it comes to politics, sport and culture, [although it belongs to Asia](https://mfa.gov.il/MFA/AboutIsrael/Maps/Pages/Israel-and-the-Region.aspx#:%7E:text=Israel%20stands%20at%20the%20crossroads,Red%20Sea%20to%20the%20south.)?

For example, Israel participates in the following organizations:

- The Eurovision song contest.
- UEFA.

Or When it comes to politic world, during the Corona crisis [Heiko Maas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heiko_Maas) , the German minister of foreign affairs, said that:

> [Germany sees Israel as part of Europe](https://www.jpost.com/health-science/germany-would-share-europe-only-covid-vaccine-with-israel-645773)

I guess we could give numerous examples.

I try to be objective, they aren't closer or more far to European culture than for example Turkey, or Islamic countries but at least Turkey has a little bit of European land.

Comment: I have a good answer to this question but I am loath to answer it because it would indicate that this is a valid line of questioning.  Whats next why do the arabs allow them to live?

Comment: Initially, I assumed this was being asked in terms of, "Why does the EU recognize Israel as a European country?"  I thought it poor, but I hacked out a response anyway.  With the clarifications - examplewise - I see that this is a culture question, not a political one.  This can be salvaged by finding a governmental organization that calls Israel European, but for now, I think it off topic.

Comment: @AffableGeek - It is an anti semetic question "why is Israel included as the friend of anyone why do they not get shunned by all?"

Comment: @Chad - that one's easy. Because arabs don't have a capability to NOT allow them to live. Palestinian National Charter to this day calls for full destruction of Israel despite them promising to remove that as part of Oslo accords.

Comment: Why good questions about Israel get closed in this website?

Comment: @Jimmy I would assume that this question was closed 7 years ago because it didn't provide a single example for its thesis which was actually of political relevance (sports leagues and TV singing competitions are not politically relevant)

Comment: Most questions relating to Isreal are not politically correct. Isreal is not nation with debatable attributes in formal western discussion. It's also the birth area of jesus and related to a germanic racial purity genocide which doesn't aid the debate.

Answer (score 7):

The same reason why some count Armenia to be European: politics. Armenia is totally in Asia, but the EU bodies consider it "culturally European" and treat as all other European countries.

Comment: Hard to say, these Caucasus countries aren't bad examples for exception, in description of Europe they don't include Israel, while your countries are included. I think Judaism isn't closer or more far culturally from Christianity than Islam. Their culture isn't so close to other European countries, for difference there is Kibbutz for example.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary who "they"?

Comment: generally Wikipedia and other definitions, here is a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe)

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary Since you brought up Kibbutzim, I'd say it's a perfect example of a European influence on Israel. While strictly not a Marxist construct, kibbutzim is recognizably influenced by Marx and Engels, whose political philosophy (of course) originated in Europe. Furthermore the Judaism related characteristics of Kibbutzim are actually more closely related to Zionism, and of course Zionism (as a philosophy) also originated in Europe (mainly by Jews, of course, but European ones).

Comment: @YannisRizos no, I am regular Hungarian without any known Jewish relatives, I just wondered about this question first when I saw Israel in Eurovision. I am not antisemitic, I don't really care if they do performance there, but I don't understand why are they considered as European in many ways.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary I don't think I called you an antisemite, and if I implied that in some way, I apologise. My only intent was to point out that Kibbutzim, which you brought forth as an example of a culture that isn't so close to European countries, is in fact a concept that's heavily influenced by concepts that originated in Europe. I wouldn't call it a European concept, but it's not as far from European culture as you seem to think it is.

Comment: @YannisRizos just I wanted to declare as non-antisemitic to be clear. I am pretty neutral in this, I have a jewish and an antisemitic friend as well.

Comment: @YannisRizos to answer to comment: Yes the basic idea origins from Europe, but still, it is not a practice here. Thinking of Ptolemaic Greek state, it was culturally European, but still it situated in Africa.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary Yes, but that didn't stop Cleopatra from competing in and even winning Eurovision ;)

Comment: true, not the best match example... :)

Comment: Cyprus is another example.  When they joined the EU, Morocco asked if they could join as well.

Comment: Well, Morocco used to participate in InterRail, @gerrit.